# AutoComplete feature in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, autocomplete

How to implement autocomplete feature in sharepoint?

Comment: You mind elaborating a little more about this *feature*?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're after Search Suggestions.
You get this as an OOTB feature with FAST Search.
Using FAST any search term that has been used and 5 times or more with an result clicked on gets promoted to a seach suggestion.
If you want this functionality to appear through out your site you'll need to change the deafult search box to use the SearchBox web part that you can find on the default.aspx of a FAST Search centre.
You can also manually prime Search Suggestions via Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Do you want to implement autocomplete for a new item/edit item form for some list, or you want to create autocomplete webpart to query list data ? Depending on your need there are multiple ways to accomplish this. you can use jquery or Microsoft ajax framework.

[Here is the example](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2010/04/search-autocomplete-for-sharepoint-2010-lists/) for auto complete web part to query list data.

Comment: here the requirement is autocompletor should display result related to search as and when user enters any text in a textbox.....like google. how is that possible using jquery

Comment: Here is an example, may be it will help -http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-query-suggestion-in-fast.html